# connecting to a different database engine depending on user input

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, netbeans

I want the user to specify the name of database and table (eg database login and table customer).

Once the user gives these details, the data in the table customer must be displayed no matter whether the database and table is created in SQL Server or MySQL.

My application is designed in NetBeans.

How can this be done?

Comment: Difficult to tell what's being asked. In order to connect to a database, the user MUST specify credentials authenticating that user. There is no way to JUST specify the database and table to which to connect. Now, once connected to a database, it is possible to construct a generic SQL query against a table, by name, and execute it.

Comment: What you are asking is akin to walking in to a library and saying to the librarian "Chapter 2, paragraph 4" and expecting them to know which book to look in.

Answer (score 1):

What your application displays to the user is completely independent of the database you are using.

In your case, connect to the database. Verify that the connection was correct, then display a window that shows the content of the table.

This is pure Java coding and more or less covered by every Java tutorial that deals with JDBC and databases.